# Use Ubuntu CD to Boot from USB Drive?

Tags: boot, usb

I have a bootable CD containing Ubuntu 14.04 Server and a bootable USB drive containing the operating system I want to install. The problem is, my PC does not support the option to boot from USB. It does support the option to boot from CD.

**My question is:**

Is it possible to boot from the Ubuntu CD and somehow tell it to then boot from the USB drive?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to boot a bootable USB drive from a CD, but not with the Ubuntu CD.

You can use the the [Plop Boot Manager](http://www.plop.at/en/bootmanagers.html)

But if your PC has a Internet connection, the [Minimal-CD](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD) would be a easier option to install Ubuntu.

And it sounds like your PC is a little bit older, perhaps you should prefer Xubuntu or Lubuntu (if you install from the Minimal CD you can select each Ubuntu flavor).